# Does Azure Premium V3 Support Remote Debugging?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Azure PremiumV2 app service plans lose the ability to attach remote debuggers over Standard app service plans:

> Remote debugging: When you scale your app to PremiumV2, you will no longer be able to use remote debugging for your apps. If you scale your App Service plan to a lower tier, you will be able to use remote debug again.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/03/23/PremiumV2-support-for-older-deployments.html

I've looked at the documentation for the new PremiumV3 app service tier, and can find no reference one way or another to remote debugging.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier

Do PremiumV3 allow for the attachment of remote debuggers, and is there any indication of the long term strategy around this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I span up a .NET 6 minimal API project, uploaded to a app service, changed the app service plan level, and where possible, attached a remote debugger from Visual Studio 2022 to observe a GET request.

I've tested each tier, and have the following results:

| Tier | Remote Debugger Support |
| --- | --- |
| F1 | YES |
| D1 | YES |
| B1 | YES |
| S1 | YES |
| P1 | YES |
| P1V2 | NO |
| P1V3 | NO |

Comment: Is consumption plan supported? Either Linux or Windows? I believe there are no settings in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

- I have created an App service with V3 plan.
- Deployed WebApp to the App service.
- Tried to Attach debugger from Visual Studio,It changed the settings of Remote Debugging to `On` but unable to hit the break point.

[image]

- Even there is an option of Remote Debugging in Azure Portal,the debugger is not attached to it.

[image]